# Using gstreamer plugins bad in android

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am trying to show h264 encodes streams inside an android application using the GStreamer SDK and Android NDK. 
My Android.mk looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := App
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := App.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT
    ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
        $(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
    endif
    GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET)
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

Beacause of missing plugins-bad I get the following error:

```
priv_gst_parse_yyparse no element "h264parse"
```

My pipe looks like the following:

```
udpsrc address=192.168.0.1 port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

So how can I include the gstreamer-plugins-bad into android build?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line instead the one you have:

```
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED)
```

Specifically this one should do the job `$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line :

```
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS)
```

in your path : `app/jni/Android.mk`